# How to launch Main Activity from static "context-less" main() method?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, root, motionevent

I have my Android app installed on my rooted phone. Using `adb shell` command, I have launched a `main(String[])` method inside a Class within that Applications package, giving the process `uid 0` (root permissions).

I have used 
`adb shell "su -c 'CLASSPATH=/data/app/my.package.name/base.apk /system/bin/app_process32 /system/bin my.package.name.Main'"`

To launch `Main` Class within `my.package.name` package.

However, all of the methods that I need the root permissions for require applications activity running, as this command does not launch the application, but instead, launches the main method inside the given class.

I could use the mentioned command to launch `main()` method within my `MainActivity`, but `OnCreate()` is not called this way and i cannot call it from static context. Making `OnCreate()` static is not an option either.

My question is, how do I launch the `MainActivity` to fire-off the `OnCreate()` method from `main()` method, preferably retaining the `uid 0` for the process?

I am trying to make a black-box auto-test application and I need these permissions to inject events into third party apps.

Comment: use `adb shell am start ...` - more [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#am)

Comment: The new process started this way will not have 'uid 0'

Comment: there is also `run-as` command - never tried it but heard that you can use it for UID switching

Comment: btw i checked the link: `"more here"` and there is `--user ` switch

Comment: `am start` cannot be used to start application as root user. To be sure, i just tried it. I am asking how to start `MainActivity` from `main()` method, retaining `uid 0`

Comment: so what did you try? `run-as` or `--user` ?

Comment: Both. They wont help as they are not executed inside my applications `main` method. they are separate processes with their own uid. They do not grant root permissions. If they did, that would be a a big and obvious security hole

Comment: Updated my post to make it clearer

Comment: I don't think you can. You need to call startActivity()` on a `Context` object but only Android can set up a `Context` object and you would need Android to launch you application first.

Comment: Actually, there is `Context.createPackageContext(String packageName, int flags)` that returns a `Context`, as if Android has launched that package. I am trying to figure out how to use that method in static context.

Comment: The method `Context.createPackageContext()` is `abstract`. How do you think you can call it unless you already have a `Context`?

Comment: In the end, i did not use it. Instead of starting activity from the process, i have started the process from the activity using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)`. Since i run on rooted device, i am able to use `super user` command.